# How to check if it's safe to reduce precision of a DECIMAL type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have a MySQL table with columns of [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) type, e.g. `DECIMAL(20,4)`. I want to reduce the precision for this column to `DECIMAL(10,2)`. Is there an easy way to verify that this will not cause any data loss (i.e. all existing values are within the precision)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing "mantissa" places. The new type won't be able to store values beyond `99999999.99`.

Therefore, it's quite easy to verify if you'll be losing data. See if any value exceeds that limit using:

```
select * from my_table where my_column > 99999999.99
```

**Edit for the decimal places:**

For the 2 decimal places at the end you can check using:

```
select * 
from my_table
where round(my_column * 100) <> my_column * 100
```

or:

```
select
from my_table
where right(format(my_column, 4), 2) <> '00'
```

Comment: What about digits in the fractional part? e.g. `123.4567`

Comment: Or `SELECT MAX(ABS(my_column)) FROM my_table`.

Answer (score -1):

The approach described by @theimpaler is sound as long as the data can’t be changed between the time you run that query and the time you redefine the field. If there is a possibility of data changing mid-process, you’ll need to do more.

A possible approach:

Comment: It seems like your post is unfinished :)